# Calculator Not Working in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a calculator function that works well in chrome but not in other browsers (edge,firefox,explorer,opera). Can anyone tell me what's wrong.Thanks

```html
<div class="content ticket_wrapper">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row header">
      <div class="cell">Ticket</div>
      <div class="cell"><div class="align"> Price</div></div>
      <div class="cell"><div class="align"> Qnty</div></div>
      <div class="cell">Total</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Normal</div>
      <div class="cell"><div class="align"> KSH 650</div></div>
      <div class="cell">
          <div class="ticket">
            <select oninput="calculate()" id="titotal" class="titotal">
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <span id="result"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Advanced</div>
      <div class="cell"><div class="align"> KSH 950</div></div>
      <div class="cell">
          <div class="ticket">
            <select oninput="calculate()" id="titotal_2" class="titotal">
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <span id="result2"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table_tots">
    <div class="row grand_total">
        <div class="cell">
            Sub Total : 
            <span id="grand_total"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="sub"> 
    <input class="submit" type="button" value="Proceed">
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('#sub').hide();
    $('.titotal').on('click', function(event){
        var one = $('#titotal').val();
        var two = $('#titotal_2').val();
        if (one>0 || two>0) {
            $('#sub').show();
        }else{
            $('#sub').hide();
        }
    });

    function calculate(){
        var mybox1 = document.getElementById('titotal').value;
        var mybox2 = document.getElementById('titotal_2').value;
        var myresult = mybox1 * 650;
        var myresult2 = mybox2 * 950;
        var total = myresult + myresult2;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = myresult;
        document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = myresult2;
        document.getElementById("grand_total").innerHTML = total;
      }
    window.onload = calculate();
```

I am building a table for a ticket purchasing website

Comment: Can you please create https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for FireFox, it is enough to change:

```
<select oninput="calculate()" id="titotal" class="titotal">
```

To:

```
<select onchange="calculate()" id="titotal" class="titotal">
```

And it works. The button is not even necessary then.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason `oninput` is not fired in edge browser.

To fix it, you can add calculate function to end of `click` handler,
so you will recalculate the sum after click.

Your code become:

```
 $('.titotal').on('click', function(event){
        var one = $('#titotal').val();
        var two = $('#titotal_2').val();
        if (one>0 || two>0) {
            $('#sub').show();
        }else{
            $('#sub').hide();
        }

        calculate();
    });
```

And you can remove `oninput` from your HTML elements.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/livadogupi/edit?html,console,output) you have a working fiddle.